Did Tanjiro become as strong as a Hashira by season 4 of the anime?
In episode 1 of season 4 of the anime, it's mentioned that Tanjiro is the first person to get a mark (which increases powers) even before than any Hashira (though 2 other Hashiras also got the mark). Is Tanjiro equally strong or stronger than a Hashira without a mark?

You could definitely make the argument that he is. Especially considering that he was able to (kinda) hold his own against, and eventually (with some help) kill Upper 4 when there are Hashira who have died by weaker. For example, I forget when, but Gyutaro (Upper 6) claimed to have killed several hashira. "Gyutaro, a character from the “Demon Slayer: Kimetsu no Yaiba” series, is known to have killed at least fifteen Hashira of the Demon Slayer Corps during his lifetime as a demon"Source, paraphrased This means that if Tanjiro was able to kill Upper 4 with less help than he had against Upper 6, and this time, the demon didn't put him in a coma, Tanjiro is definitely stronger than he once was and possibly out-strengthing some hashira. He is most definitely stronger than the following:

Shinobu (That's the given, she only a Hashira because Kanae needed to be replaced)

Tengen. Tengen got career-ending injuries from Upper 6. Tanjiro not only survive 6 but also beat 4.

Obinai

Maybe Kyojuro. Not exact, but you could make that argument. It's hard to say for sure because Kyojuro fought a demon with a huge power gap between anything Tanjiro faced in S4, so while you can make that case, it depends on your definition of "stronger". If "stronger" means "survive the fight" then that makes Aoi Kanzaki "strong" for surviving final selection, for example. If "stronger" means ability to hold one's own against a significantly more powerful opponent, than Tanjiro is not stronger than Kyojuro.



I disagree with the Kyojuro part. I think it should've been Obanai that he's stronger than.

It's later mentioned in an episode of the anime

 Zenitsu tells Tanjiro he was able to fight at the level of the wind hashira (with whom he had a fight that lasted several hours, and who is the second strongest hashira)


What episode was this?

@daemons at the end of episode 5 of Hashira geiko hen . It was an awesome episode btw

Till the end of season 3, Tanjiro trains his both breathing techniques and tries his fullest to become strong so that he can fight Muzan and defeat him but still, he isn't as strong as Hashira. We can say that he was stronger than weaker Hashira like Shinobu. But he was not stronger than any other Hashira.
In the next season, he will find more power and discover new forms of his breathing technique, and will also be able to use Transparent World.

Tanjiro Kamado, the main protagonist of the anime Demon Slayer, does in fact achieved incredible success in his demon slayer career. Whether or not his strength is in parity with other Hashiras is a topic of debate and is a matter of opinion.
!!WARNING: LARGE AMOUNTS OF SPOILERS AHEAD!!
Let's go over his strength and achievements:

 Before he even became a demon slayer, he achieved incredible success in multiple ways:


  1. He confronted, fought, and partially succeeded (with Nezuko's help) in defeating a normal demon in a temple. This happened right after the slaughter of his family, and thus before any training. The mere fact that he could win a fight with a demon without any training is incredible enough. Considering the additional emotional, physical, psychological, and mental stress he endured after the tragic loss of his family, this feat is outstanding.


  2. He sliced through the toughest boulder of all time (with Sabito and Makomo's help). It was revealed by Sabito that while all pupils of Urokodaki Sakonji need to slice through a boulder with their katana in order to gain permission from Urokodaki to join the final selection, the boulder Tanjiro sliced through was the toughest, hardest, and largest boulder of all time. This feat alone was incredible, since that means he sliced through a boulder that even Water Hashira Tomioka Giyu might not have been able to slice through.


  3. He killed the Hand Demon. This happened in the final selection, thus before he even became a demon slayer. This achievement is especially amazing since even Sabito, Giyu, and all other final selection attendees wasn't able to kill this deformed demon.


  4. He killed a strong demon in his first mission. The swamp demon, a deformed demon that eats young girls, is quite strong given its three bodies and its ability to hide inside a moving underground swamp that have little oxygen inside. Considering that Tanjiro did this on his first mission shows that he is indeed a talented slayer.


  5. He killed Yahaba and Susamaru on his second mission. Although it is later revealed that both Yahaba and Susamaru weren't a member of the twelve kizuki, they nevertheless are strong opponents that have nearly the power of blood moons.


  6. Not really an achievement, but Tanjiro is in fact the first slayer to meet the demon king Kibutsuji Muzan. It shows that he was probably fated to kill the demon king.


  7. He killed Kyogai, a former Lower Rank Six of the twelve kizuki. This is in Tanjiro's third mission, and he was already able to kill a former Upper Rank, which demonstrated his superb abilities, especially given that he was already injured in the Yahaba/Susamaru fight just a few days prior.


  8. He killed the Spider Mother, assisted Inosuke in killing the large and powerful Marionette, and also was able to hold his own against an active member of the twelve kizuki, the Lower Rank Five Rui. Although he wasn't able to kill Rui, he almost killed him with his newly discovered breathing style, the Hinokami Kagura. His ability to use two breathing styles, and that one of them was actually a rusty version of the most powerful style that Yorichii created, the Sun breathing, were sufficient to demonstrate that he might as well be more powerful than a Hahira.


  9. He, along with Inosuke, managed to kill Lower Rank One Enmu. Tanjiro also killed Upper Rank Six with the help of Tengen, Inosuke and Zenitsu. He also killed Upper Rank 4 Hantengu with Mitsuri, Genya and Nezuko, thereby showcasing his superhuman endurance, strong will, and the power of two breathing styles.


  10. He passes the entire Hashira training, a feat few other slayers managed to achieve.

Thus, my opinion is that his abilities far surpass some of the Hashira, with the exception of Stone Hashira Gyomei Himejima, Water Hashira Tomioka Giyu, Wind Hashira Sanemi Shinazugawa, Mist Hashira Muichiro Tokito, and Fire Hashira Kyojuro Rengoku, thus placing him in the middle.

I'd say if it wasn't for the existence of demons like Kyogai or whoever Lower 6 was at that time, the swamp demon may have been lower-moon strength,

@DekoRevinio I completely agree. The swamp demon is indeed a very powerful demon, so much so that I also wondered why it didn't become a lower rank 6.
